# Gnu parallel combine args from stdin and file

Tags: bash, redis, parallel-processing, gnu

I am using gnu parallel command to monitor few redis endpoints and than execute all commands on new endpoints. 
Currently command looks like:

```
parallel --ungroup redis-cli -h {} monitor :::: old-server-list | cut -d  "]" -f 2 | parallel --ungroup -k ./writter.sh {}
```

and writter.sh

```
parallel redis-cli -h {} $1 ::: redis-host-1 redis-host-2
```

but i am getting inconsistent time needed for commands executed on old vs new endpoints cause connections to new redis is closing and opening all the time.  is it possible to pass arguments to parallel command from stdin and file at the same time? to combine each record from 'new-server-list' with same stdin input to avoid calling script?

something like:

```
parallel ... | cut ... | parallel redis-cli -h {<line from new-server-list>} {<stdin from pipe>}
```

that should be executed as:

```
redis-cli -h redis-host-1 stdin_output1
redis-cli -h redis-host-2 stdin_output1
redis-cli -h redis-host-1 stdin_output2
redis-cli -h redis-host-2 stdin_output2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `paste` to paste two columns side-by-side, one from a file and one from a command:

So, look at this:

```
seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And a file called `list.txt` running the other way:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Now `paste` does this:

```
paste list.txt <(seq 10)
10  1
9   2
8   3
7   4
6   5
5   6
4   7
3   8
2   9
1   10
```

Which you can feed into **GNU Parallel**:

```
paste list.txt <(seq 10) | parallel -k --colsep '\t' echo {2} {1}
1 10
2 9
3 8
4 7
5 6
6 5
7 4
8 3
9 2
10 1
```

Comment: i edited my question for better understanding. i need to insert args in 3th pipe and combine each stdin with all records from file. not sure i can make table inside 3th..

Comment: I still don't understand, sorry! Do you want all permutations of two files? If so, you can make a file called `list1` with 4 lines in, and another called`list2.txt` with 3 lines in it and do `parallel -a list1.txt -a list2.txt echo {1} {2}`for 12 lines of output, i.e. all permutations.

Comment: for example, i can successfully write to redis-endpoint.com:
`parallel --ungroup redis-cli -h {} monitor :::: old-server-list | cut -d  "]" -f 2 | parallel --ungroup redis-cli -h redis-endpoint.com {} `
now i need to replace redis-endpoint.com with multiple endpoints so i can write same command to all of them. so i need to make permutations with stdin and endpoints (originally in file), 1:n

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of reading from the file '-'?

```
parallel --line-buffer redis-cli -h {} monitor :::: old-server-list |
  cut -d  "]" -f 2 |
  parallel --line-buffer -k redis-cli -h {2} {1} :::: - ::: redis-host-1 redis-host-2
```

Use `--dry-run` to see if those are the command you want run:

```
parallel --line-buffer redis-cli -h {} monitor :::: old-server-list |
  cut -d  "]" -f 2 |
  parallel --dry-run --line-buffer -k redis-cli -h {2} {1} :::: - ::: redis-host-1 redis-host-2
```

(Never use `-u` if you are going to actually use the output. There is a risk that half-lines will mix - thus messing up your output. Use `--line-buffer` instead, it guarantees full lines).

Comment: `parallel --line-buffer redis-cli -h {} monitor :::: old-server-list |
  cut -d  "]" -f 2 |
  parallel --line-buffer -k redis-cli -h {args from :::} {line from pipe}  ::: redis-host-1 redis-host-2 ` so i need to concat output from pipe and args from ::: (i used file to store enpoints firstplace, but i can use them as args from line). Is it even possible to concat those 2? output from pipe with args on line?

Comment: I swapped {1} and {2} which I think you ware asking for. Use `--dry-run` to confirm if it really are the commands you want run.